# how to align div to the left and color its left border blue?

Tags: css

I have a main div.

In it I want to create another div (frankly, to put AdSense in it).

I want to create an inner div.

Align it to the left and color its left border blue.

I attach my unsuccessful try

please advise

http://jsfiddle.net/7hbK8/

[image]
I have the big light-blue div, and the blue div

I want to add the orange div with red\blue (what ever) border.

Comment: Hey, here's the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/7hbK8/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed a semi colon:

http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/7hbK8/4/

Comment: how can I center it (left cneter) ?

Comment: left center?
If you want it to be always in the middle, you need to specify the width, and add `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;` and remove the `float:right`

Comment: You can remove the float and add margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I meant aligned to left, but at the middle of the left most area

Comment: I'm not sure what you do you mean, something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/7hbK8/8/ If not, can you send some examples maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bla">
    <div class="inner">
    blablablablablablab
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​

.inner
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-left-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}​
```

Comment: how can I center it (left cneter) ?

Comment: I meant aligned to left, but at the middle of the left most area

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition was wrong; it should be something like this:

```
.bla
{
 float: right;
 border-left: 1px solid #ff0000 ;
}​
```

You would change the `float` to either `right`, `left` or `none`, depending on your needs. Also, the color you posted (#ff0000) is not blue but red.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean with 'inner div' so I made this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7hbK8/6/

Comment: how can I center it (left cneter) ?